# What is the size of the image for UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, navigationbar

There are three simulator or iPhone devices, as given below

```
iPhone

iPhone (Retina 3.5 inch)

iPhone (Retina 4 inch)
```

I want to implement the following method,  for navigation bar.

```
- (UINavigationController *)navigationController {

    nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
           initWithRootViewController:[self demoController]];

    // If Iphone/iPod Touch
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        // If iPhone 5 or new iPod Touch

        NSLog(@"The height is %f ", [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height );

        NSLog(@"The width is %f ", [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);


        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){
            [nav.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"] forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
        } else{
            // Regular iPhone
            [nav.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_classic.png"] forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];

        }
    }

    return nav;

}
```

I want to know proper size of Navigation image, nav.png, and condition, so that i can work for all three devices.

As I used 320x44 for nav classic, but it looks small in device **iPhone (Retina 3.5 inch)**
So, As I use nav.png for all, its looks bigger **iPhone**

**1. What are proper sizes of UINavigationBar?**

**2. What is proper logic to use them?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in the size of the navigation bar for iphone 3.5 retina and iphone 4 retina. The real size of the image for this retina devices is 640x88. You can also made two images for the navigation bar one at 320x44 (for non retina devices) and one at 640x88. You have to name this image something like NavImage.png and NavImage@2x.png , in this way the os will automaticcaly use the correct image.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar-iPhone.png"]forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

used this code for setting background image to navigation bar no worry about size iphone 3.5,iphone 4 it will automatically adjust.

Comment: NavBar-iPhone.png What is size of this image?

Comment: Its not working, please see at you end and edit answer, and iphone 4 and iphone 5 ratina, doesn't match 320x44,

Comment: so used big size image and try to use autolayout.

Comment: Thanks for such useless advice. If you do not exact answer, you must not post irrelevant answer.